# XML parser to get result in Name and Value pair in java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

I need to parse the dynamically generated XML files. So want to parse the xml results in Name and Value pair and will insert in to some Hashmap. So which parsing mechanism is easy and more robust to parse the XML in Name, value pair?

My XML looks like,

```
<Address>
    <Name>Rahul</Name>
    <ID>2345</ID>
    <City>Pune</City>
    <Street>Gandhi Nagar</Street>
</Address>
```

I need to get the parsing result as,

```
Name:Rahul
ID:2345
City:Pune
Street:Gandhi Nagar
```

Comment: Do you know about JAXB.. ?

Comment: No. But I will definitely look at JAXB

Comment: Okay If you have XML . generate .xsd from it.. You can find lot online to geenrate .xsd from XML, and then You will have java classes package.. Uset that package to Unmarshal the XML .. Now You will have all the data available in form of class objects..

Comment: Great. But the form fields may change some times. How do I handle that? The form fields should be dynamic. Can I handle with your suggestion?

Comment: Nothing to do with form fields here.. Unless untill the tag names changes.. I mean `<Name>,<Address>` these things should not change.. their values can change..

Comment: I mean the tags may increase or decrease <Name>,<Address> . I am not worrying about values here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use JAXB

```
class Address {
    @XmlElement(name="Name")
    private String name;
    @XmlElement(name="ID")
    private String id;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getID() {
        return id;
    }
}

public class Test { 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Address addr = JAXB.unmarshal(new File("address.xml"), Address.class);
    }
}
```

If you dont know fields in advance you can parse in Map using StAX:

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    XMLStreamReader xr = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream("1.xml"));
    while(xr.hasNext()) {
        int e = xr.next();
        if (e == XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT) {
            String name = xr.getLocalName();
            xr.next();
            String value = xr.getText();
            map.put(name, value);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: This solution is good only if you know the fileds in advance, if it is not the case it wont work

Comment: You can parse into a map using StAX

Comment: Added StAX based parsing example

Comment: Interesting, try     String value = null;
    try {
     value = xr.getText();
    } catch (Exception ex) {

Comment: I have one final query, shall I ask here Or Do I need to create a new question?

Comment: Added my query here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28501128/illegalstateexception-while-parsing-the-xml